# Learning a scripting language

Tags: learning, scripting

I believe every programmer must learn about a core programming language and a scripting language. Seriously I've no hand in any languages like Python, JavaScript, JScript, CScript etc. I'm native Windows Developer and which scripting language would be the best one to do some automation/web related stuffs.

Comment: I believe you're asking for a good scripting language to startup with?

Comment: @Nipuna - Yes exactly. I'm sure every scripting languages are having it's own goodness for certain things.

Answer (score 11):

[Python](http://python.org/). Period.
Google has very good introductory [lectures.](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/introduction.html)

**EDIT**
Why?

Because Python is:

- Easy to understand for beginners
- Scalable (can be used for developing small AND large project)
- Portable
- Cross-Platform
- Object-Oriented
- Simple
- FUN

Comment: Why not Pearl? ;) No seriously: Start with Python or Pearl and when you are comfortable with one, you can at least read or do some basic stuff with the other one. Is someone else already using a scripting language at your current company? Might ease the learning and give you some real projects.

Comment: Please expand your answer.  Why is Python a good language to start with?  What about it would be hare to learn as a first language?

Comment: @Christian: I assumed you meant [Perl](http://www.perl.org/), although I was surprised to find there is a [PEARL](http://www.irt.uni-hannover.de/pearl/index_en.html) programming language.

Comment: @Jaime: You're right.

Comment: @Christian: I know Python *very* well, but even the best Perl code I've seen doesn't make more sense to me than e.g. Scala code (to pick a language I know equally little about). That is to say, I get what most of it propably does, but I don't really understand the finer points.

Comment: @Sorantis - Thanks for your reply. I was actually beginning with Python. The language features attracted me and also it's cross platform. I was actually looking in to learning something not solely associated to Windows platform. Of course @glenatron's reply really make sense in the context of Windows platform and web related things (actually my question was phrased like that)

Comment: @Christian : How can you even think about recommending Perl if you cannot even spell it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

For web stuff, JavaScript is extremely useful. It complements any server-side programming you are doing in other languages and it gives you a taste of scripting that is pretty easy to learn and can be tested right there in the browser.

For windows automation I use Powershell a lot. It doesn't feel much like a real language ( maybe Perl, a touch ) and you wouldn't use it to write applications, but it really is very handy for automating things in Windows that you need to automate, and as it can reach into .net it can actually do a lot of clever things with your system- more than you might expect.

If you want to learn something for fun then maybe start with Ruby. It's flexible, expressive and powerful but mostly it is an absolute pleasure to program with.

Comment: Thanks... I've heard of Ruby connected to Web. but never tried it before. Also you perfectly answered my question. I also want to learn something not really depends on a single platform. In that sense Ruby and Python make sense.

Answer (score 3):

General purpose? Then either Python or Perl. I'd say the latter was more used but it doesn't really matter, just pick one of the two and go with it!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue with Windows development only, then you should go with [**VBScript**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt.aspx) and/or [**JScript**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yek4tbz0.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For web related stuff I would recommend you to use JavaScript and PHP as a start. both are very common scripting languages and you can find many articles to get a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to start with JavaScript as one should have some knowledge in Front End/Client Side Scripting Languages and JavaScript should be the starting point.